# BigQuery - nest operations within partition in order to aggregate consecutive records from a table with 17 billion records

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I'm pretty new to SQL and BigQuery, and have been slamming my head against the wall trying to figure out a feasible solution to this problem for a week now. The two solutions that I've got don't scale.

**Background**

Have a BigQuery table with 17 Billion records. Each record represents one device ping. Each records contains a timestamp, an ID to identify the user, and the name of the location that received the ping.

Take this data table, partition it by the ID and sort by timestamp. Then you have a chronologically ordered set of pings. A user may have 1 ping to location A followed by 7 to location B followed by 2 to location C, and, 2 more to A.

```
ID        timestamp             Location
ABC123    2017-10-12 10:20:37   A
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:15:21   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:21:47   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:25:05   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:32:12   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:36:24   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:47:13   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:59:08   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 12:04:42   C
ABC123    2017-10-12 17:04:52   C
ABC123    2017-10-12 19:15:37   A
ABC123    2017-10-12 19:18:37   A
```

What I would like to do, is take this table and produce a new one with one row per "trip". Where a trip is a group of consecutive pings, with a "first_ping" and a "last_ping" column. In the event that a trip consists of 1 ping, that timestamp is both the first and last ping.

```
ID        first_ping            last_ping             Location
ABC123    2017-10-12 10:20:37   2017-10-12 10:20:37   A
ABC123    2017-10-12 11:15:21   2017-10-12 11:59:08   B
ABC123    2017-10-12 12:04:42   2017-10-12 17:04:52   C
ABC123    2017-10-12 19:15:37   2017-10-12 19:18:37   A
```

**Attempts at a Solution**

**Python**

I've never worked with data this large, and I've always worked with Python. So my first attempt at a solution was a Python script that:

1. Queries BQ for all the data for one ID
2. Sorts the data by timestamp
3. Uses the diff function on "Location" to figure out when it changes
4. Uses cumsum() to flag all the items for each group of pings with the same value.
5. uses df.groupby() on the cumsum() to get one row per record, and first() and last() to get the first_ping and last_ping values.

This solution produces the output I need, but is not feasible for 17 billion records and 69M unique IDs. It takes about 10 seconds per ID, and that's about 190K hours of run time.

**SQL**

```
WITH visitWithIsChange AS 
(select
   *,
   LAG(location,1,'') OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp) previous,
    CASE 
     WHEN (LAG(location,1,'') 
           OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp)) = location
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
     END ischange
 FROM `ping_table` ORDER BY user_id, timestamp),
 visitsWithcumsum AS (
   SELECT 
      t1.*,
      SUM(t2.ischange) AS cumulativeSum 
   FROM visitWithIsChange t1
        INNER JOIN
             visitWithIsChange t2
               ON
                 t1.local_timestamp >=t2.local_timestamp
                 AND
                 t1.user_id=t2.user_id
   GROUP BY 
     t1.local_timestamp,
     t1.user_id,
     t1.chain_id,
     t1.previous,
     t1.isChange
   ORDER BY user_id, timestamp
)
SELECT 
  MIN(timestamp) AS first_ping,
  MAX(local_timestamp) AS last_ping,
  user_id,
  chain_id,
FROM visitsWithcumsum
GROUP BY
  user_id,
  cumulativeSum,
  chain_id,
ORDER BY user_id, first_ping
```

I know that the problem with the SQL statement is the use of ORDER BY outside of the partitions. BigQuery throws resource exceeded errors every time ORDER BY is called on more than a couple hundred thousand rows. My understanding is that this occurs because an ORDER BY statement requires all of the data being ordered to reside on one node.

**Questions**

1. Is it possible to use the above SQL approach, but nest all of the logic within a partition statement? Basically, partition by user_id and do all of the ordering, cumsum, etc., within that partition?
2. Is there a better approach to solving this problem?

I appreciate any and all input. I'm at a complete loss as to the best way to solve this, and feel way out of my depth.

Answer (score 0):

The `cumulativeSum` should be calculated using a *cumulative sum* instead of a non-equi-join:

```
WITH visitWithIsChange AS 
(select
   *,
    CASE 
     WHEN (LAG(location,1,'') 
           OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY timestamp)) = location
           THEN 0
           ELSE 1
     END ischange
 FROM `ping_table`
 -- I don't now about BigQuery, but why do you need this?
 --ORDER BY user_id, timestamp
 ),
 visitsWithcumsum AS (
   SELECT 
      *,
      SUM(ischange)
      OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
            ORDER BY timestamp
            ROWS UNBOUNDED PREDECING) AS cumulativeSum 
   FROM visitWithIsChange  
)
SELECT 
  MIN(timestamp) AS first_ping,
  MAX(local_timestamp) AS last_ping,
  user_id,
  chain_id,
FROM visitsWithcumsum
GROUP BY
  user_id,
  cumulativeSum,
  chain_id,
ORDER BY user_id, first_ping
```

Comment: Hey @dnoeth, thank you very much for your answer. I was able to kick the query off before leaving the office, and it ran successfully. No resource exceeded error.

The ORDER BY that you commented out was indeed extraneous, and not due to BigQuery. This is my first time using SQL (and first time with big data). So I'm making mistakes, but trying to learn more.

I just need to QA the results from this query tomorrow morning when I get to the office.

Answer (score 0):

Try below version (BigQuery Standard SQL)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  MIN(timestamp) AS first_ping, 
  MAX(timestamp) AS last_ping, 
  ANY_VALUE(location) AS location
FROM (
  SELECT id, timestamp, location,
    COUNTIF(flag) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT *, 
      location != LAG(location) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp) flag
    FROM `project.dataset.ping_table`
  )
)
GROUP BY id, grp
```

Comment: Hey @Mikhail-Berlyant, thank you for your answer! I will give it a shot when I get to my computer in the morning.